# Why does Model Binding Select Method fire twice when sorting and while using a Master Page?

Tags: listview, webforms, master-pages, model-binding, asp.net-4.5

I've set up a very simple ListView using minimal coding to leverage .NET 4.5 modelbinding for WebForms.  I've used modelbinding successfully on several site pages and am fairly familiar with it, but only recently discovered the code fetches data twice when sorting.  I've distilled it down to this test case and verified the issue occurs only when using it within a MasterPage.

ASPX/CS:

```
  //webform-test.aspx
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="WebformTest.Master" CodeBehind="webform-test.aspx.cs" Inherits="IPA.webform_test" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        Test<br>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvEmployee" runat="server" ItemType="My.Entities.Employee" SelectMethod="lvEmployee_GetData">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnE" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="edit" /></td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="id" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="LastName" /></td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="FirstName" /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkId" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="id">Id</asp:LinkButton></th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </asp:Content>

  //webform-test.aspx.cs
    using My.Entities;
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace IPA
    {
        public partial class webform_test : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }

            public IQueryable<My.Entities.Employee> lvEmployee_GetData()
            {
                var ent = Employee.GetAll();
                return ent;
            }
        }
    }
```

MASTER:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebformTest.Master.cs" Inherits="IPA.WebformTest" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>TEST PAGE</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body class="cbp-spmenu-push admin">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>Master</div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="foot" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    using System;

    namespace IPA
    {
        public partial class WebformTest : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint on `var ent = Employee.GetAll();` and debug, it grabs the data fine, then when I click sort, it hits that breakpoint again, then goes to the MasterPage and after the Master's PageLoad, goes right back the breakpoint and loads data again (stepping through with F11).  It's that last part I don't understand, as the rest is totally familiar stuff.  Is there something I am missing with the ModelBinding cycle?

Why does it do this and more importantly how can I affect it so it only fetches the data once per postback?

ADDITIONAL/UPDATED INFO:
I replaced the ListView with a GridView like:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" ItemType="My.Entities.Employee" DataKeyNames="id" SelectMethod="gvEmployee_GetData" AllowSorting="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

This does **not** hit my data retrieval twice.  This is both relieving and frustrating, and puts the spotlight on my ListView implementation or the ListView control itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem again in another project.  The problem occurred because I had set this directive in my Masterpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebformTest.Master.cs"
    Inherits="IPA.WebformTest" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false" %>
```

By removing `ViewStateMode="Disabled"`, thus defaulting to Enabled, the issue resolved.  I'm not sure why and I will leave that for a new question.

It wasn't posting back twice.  It simply hit the GetData method twice in a row, with apparently nothing in between [i.e. with F11 step-debugging].